# Opengl Sierpinski Shader based C code in Visual Studio2012 & 2010

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm doing my first steps in OpenGl Shader base programming and computer graphics. I'm trying the following example, but when I try to compile the project I got the following error:

**fragment shader failed to link. vertex shader failed to link.
  ERROR: Not all shaders has valid object code**

i tried running the program in Visual Studio 2012 and 2010. glut library version is 3.7 and glew library version is 1.10.0.  what is the problem?

## .cpp Program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glew.h>
#include <glut.h>
#include <gl.h>


#pragma comment(lib,"glew32.lib")
#define NoP 50000

GLuint InitShader(char *, char *);
void mydisplay();


struct points
{   GLfloat x,y,z;
};
void init();
void Sierpinski(points Num[]);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
    glutInit(&argc,  argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutCreateWindow("Sierpinski 3D");
    glewInit();
    init();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glutDisplayFunc(mydisplay);
    glutMainLoop();
}

void init()
{
    points  Num[NoP];
    Sierpinski(Num);

    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);//set the color for clearing the display
    glPointSize(2); // set the point size
    // Creating a program object containing shader files
    GLuint program;
    program = InitShader("vshader.glsl","fshader.glsl");
    glUseProgram(program);

    //Creating a buffer object containing Sirepinski verteces data
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Num), Num, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //Make a conncetion between data in object buffer and "vPosition in vertex shader
    GLuint location = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( location );
    glVertexAttribPointer( location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,0, 0);//BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
}
void mydisplay()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); //the clear call will affect the color buffer
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS,0,NoP);//Rendering verteces data
    glFlush();  //Empty all commands buffer, causing all issued commands to be executed as quickly as they are accepted by the actual rendering engine
}

static char * ReadShaderSource(char * ShaderFile)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(ShaderFile,"rt");
    if (!fp) return NULL;
    long size=0;
    while (!feof(fp))
    {
      fgetc (fp);
      size++;
    }
    size--;//EOF should not be counted
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char * buf= new char[size + 1];
    fread(buf, 1, size,fp);
    buf[size]=0;// string is NULL terminated
    fclose(fp);
    return buf;
}
GLuint InitShader(char * vShaderFile, char * fShaderFile)
{ 
    char * svs, * sfs; 
    GLuint program, VertexShader, FragmentShader;
    program = glCreateProgram();
    VertexShader =  glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    svs=ReadShaderSource(vShaderFile);
    glShaderSource(VertexShader,1,(const GLchar **)&svs,NULL);
    glCompileShader(VertexShader);

    // reading GLSL compiler error messages for vertex shader
    GLint compiled;
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
    if(!compiled)
    {   printf("/n failed to compile");
        GLint logSize;
        glGetShaderiv(VertexShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&logSize);
        char * logMsg = new char[logSize];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShader, logSize, NULL, logMsg);
        printf("\n  %s",logMsg);
        delete [] logMsg;
        getchar();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    FragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    sfs = ReadShaderSource(fShaderFile);
    glShaderSource(FragmentShader, 1, (const GLchar **)&sfs, NULL);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShader);

    // reading GLSL compiler error messages for fragment shader
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
    if(!compiled) 
    {   printf("\n failed to compile");
        GLint logSize2;
        glGetShaderiv(FragmentShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&logSize2);
        char * logMsg2 = new char[logSize2];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShader, logSize2, NULL, logMsg2);
        printf("\n  %s",logMsg2);
        delete [] logMsg2;
        getchar();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glAttachShader(program,VertexShader);
    glAttachShader(program, FragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    // reading GLSL linker error messages for program object
    GLint linked;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked);
    if(!linked)
    {   printf("/n failed to link");
        GLint logSize;
        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&logSize);
        char * logMsg = new char[logSize];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(program, logSize, NULL, logMsg);
        printf("\n  %s",logMsg);
        delete [] logMsg;
        getchar();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glUseProgram(program);
    return program;
}
void Sierpinski(points Num[])
{
    int j;
    points  Vertices[4]={{-1.0,-1.0, -1.0},{1.0,-1.0,-1.0},{0.0,1.0,-1.0},{0.0,0.0,1.0}};
    Num[0].x = 0;
    Num[0].y = 0;
    Num[0].z = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<NoP;i++)
    {
        j = rand()  % 4;
        Num[i].x = (Vertices[j].x + Num[i - 1].x)/2;
        Num[i].y = (Vertices[j].y + Num[i - 1].y)/2;
        Num[i].z = (Vertices[j].z + Num[i - 1].z)/2;
    }

}
```

## vshader.glsl

```
#version 130
in vec4 vPosition;
out vec4 color;
void main()
{  

    gl_Position = vPosition;
    color = vPosition;
}
```

## fshader.glsl

```
#version 130
in vec4 color;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4((1.0 + color.xyz)/2.0,1.0);
}
```

Comment: You know there are easier ways to get the file size of a shader, right? `fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END)`, `ftell (fp)`, `frewind (fp)`... since shader files are unlikely to exceed 4 GiB in length, this is pretty safe to do :P Generally you would consider `ftello (...)` (Linux/OSX/BSD)/`_ftelli64 (...)` (Windows) or `fstat (...)` (far less portable, since it is POSIX and not std. C) to get the file size if you had larger files. But in no case do you actually need to loop through the file like you're doing now, that is highly inefficient.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: or better, use `fstat()`.

Comment: @kusma: How is that any better? That decreases portability, and shaders are never larger than 4 GiB.

Comment: Because on Windows, it only queries the directory-entry of the file-system, and not the much larger and more costly file-entry. And in reality, it doesn't affect portability in any way, as it's in both POSIX and Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work fine:

[image: triangle]

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>

void CheckStatus( GLuint obj )
{
    GLint status = GL_FALSE;
    if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
    if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
    if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
    GLchar log[ 1 << 17 ] = { 0 };
    if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
    if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
    std::cerr << log << std::endl;
    exit( -1 );
}

void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
    glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
    glCompileShader( shader );
    CheckStatus( shader );
    glAttachShader( program, shader );
    glDeleteShader( shader );
}

GLuint LoadProgram( const char* vert, const char* geom, const char* frag )
{
    GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
    if( vert ) AttachShader( prog, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vert );
    if( geom ) AttachShader( prog, GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER, geom );
    if( frag ) AttachShader( prog, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, frag );
    glLinkProgram( prog );
    CheckStatus( prog );
    return prog;
}

#define GLSL(version, shader) "#version " #version "\n" #shader

const char* vert = GLSL
(
    130,
    in vec4 vPosition;
    out vec4 color;
    void main()
    {  
        gl_Position = vPosition;
        color = vPosition;
    }
);

const char* frag = GLSL
(
    130,
    precision mediump float;
    in vec4 color;
    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4((1.0 + color.xyz)/2.0,1.0);
    }
);


#define NoP 50000

struct points
{   
    GLfloat x,y,z;
};

void Sierpinski(points Num[])
{
    int j;
    points  Vertices[4]={{-1.0,-1.0, -1.0},{1.0,-1.0,-1.0},{0.0,1.0,-1.0},{0.0,0.0,1.0}};
    Num[0].x = 0;
    Num[0].y = 0;
    Num[0].z = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<NoP;i++)
    {
        j = rand()  % 4;
        Num[i].x = (Vertices[j].x + Num[i - 1].x)/2;
        Num[i].y = (Vertices[j].y + Num[i - 1].y)/2;
        Num[i].z = (Vertices[j].z + Num[i - 1].z)/2;
    }
}

void init()
{
    points  Num[NoP];
    Sierpinski(Num);

    GLuint program = LoadProgram( vert, NULL, frag );
    glUseProgram(program);

    //Creating a buffer object containing Sirepinski verteces data
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Num), Num, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //Make a conncetion between data in object buffer and "vPosition in vertex shader
    GLuint location = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( location );
    glVertexAttribPointer( location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,0, 0);//BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
}

void mydisplay()
{
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);//set the color for clearing the display
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); //the clear call will affect the color buffer

    glPointSize(2); // set the point size
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS,0,NoP);//Rendering verteces data

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,  argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutCreateWindow("Sierpinski 3D");
    glewInit();
    init();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glutDisplayFunc(mydisplay);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Make sure you use [FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/), [Nate's GLUT](http://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html) is way, way old.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to Run your Code, Also i downloaded the FreeGlut version you mentioned and used it. but I got several errors like: 
**error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewAttachShader**

Comment: Did you link against `glew32.lib`?

Comment: Thanks. i Linked it and the Errors gone. but now when i Run the project i  get this message at cmd and exit: 
**Fragment Shader failed to compile with the following errors: Declaration must include a precision qualifier or the default precision must have been previously declared.**

Comment: What's your `GL_VERSION`, `GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION` and `GL_VENDOR`?

Comment: sorry i dont know how should i check these versions?

Comment: Print out the values of `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`, `glGetString(GL_VENDOR)`, etc. after `glewInit()`.

Comment: GL_VERSION: **2.1.8787**

VENDER: **ATI TECH INC**

GSL: **1.30**

Comment: Oh wow.  That's all sorts of wonky.  Upgrade your video driver and/or add a `precision mediump float;` to the top of both shaders.

Comment: I double-checked the GLSL spec and you should only need the `precision mediump float;` in the fragment shader.  But only for `#version 130`.  The ARB fixed that in `#version 140` by adding an implicit `precision highp float;` to fragment shaders.